# Агрегирующая функция count дублирует максимальное значение в кортеже

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

**Задача: вывести имя автора, название статьи, лайки статьи, дизлайки статьи.**

Есть таблицы и их атрибуты:

```
-articles
    -id
    -user_id
    -title

-likes
    -user_id
    -content_id

-dislikes
    -user_id
    -content_id

-users
    -id
    -username
```

SQL запрос:

```
SELECT users.username, articles.title, count(likes.content_id) as like_count, count(dislike.content_id) as dislike_count FROM articles
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.content_id = articles.id
LEFT JOIN dislike ON dislike.content_id = articles.id
GROUP BY likes.content_id, dislike.content_id
```

**Ошибка:**
like_count и dislike_count дублируются, по максимальному значению одного из них, в кортеже.

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: *В чем моя ошибка?* Формально - в том, что Вы то ли не понимаете, то ли понимаете, но не учитываете эффекта связывания таблиц. Если статья-юзер связаны 1:1 и их связывание не увеличивает количества записей, то с лайками и дизлайками это не так - если их по два, связывание даст 4 объединённых записи. Так что для правильного результата нужен COUNT(DISTINCT). А реально - проблема в кривой структуре. Лайк и дизлайк - это одна сущность, и зачем её порезали на две таблицы - непонятно.

Comment: Если использовать COUNT(DISTINCT), то ответ будет состоять из количества уникальных внешних ключей. В моем случае нужно найти все повторяющиеся записи в атрибуте content_id (в таблицах likes/dislikes).

Я разделил одну сущность на две, для

Comment: Что-то как-то маловменяемо... покажите на примере, что ли, по 2-3 значения и требуемый результат...

Comment: Ссылка на мини-отчет  https://ibb.co/xDgFqJQ
Там же и SQL запрос, в описании

Comment: Чёт баланс по лайкам в отчёте не сходится...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не понял из объяснений, в т.ч. в комментариях... но из чисто общих соображений

```
SELECT users.username, 
       articles.title, 
       likes.like_count, 
       dislikes.dislike_count 
FROM articles
JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) like_count
            FROM likes
            GROUP BY content_id ) likes ON likes.content_id = articles.id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) dislike_count 
            FROM dislikes
            GROUP BY content_id ) dislikes ON dislikes.content_id = articles.id
```

PS. `LEFT JOIN` для `users` нужен только в случае, если есть статьи без авторов (или с несуществующими авторами).

Comment: СУБД SQLite3 (DB Browser) ругается:
Result: wrong number of arguments to function COUNT()

Comment: Блин, SQLite... ок, ща. Готово.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш труд) все работает как надо, буду разбирать запрос)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.username, articles.title, count(likes.content_id) as like_count, 
count(dislike.content_id) as dislike_count 
FROM articles
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.content_id = articles.id
LEFT JOIN dislike ON dislike.content_id = articles.id
GROUP BY users.username,articles.title
```